# Query which group data with same values in the last X days

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to get a list of the 5 most used `model_id` from my table in the last 14 days. The problem is that I can't find a way to group `model_id` to avoid having the same `model_id` multiple time in the result.

**media table**

```
+----+-------+----------+---------------------+
| id | title | model_id |        date         |
+----+-------+----------+---------------------+
|  1 |   ... |        1 | 2017-10-04 01:47:46 |
|  2 |   ... |        1 | 2017-10-03 02:47:46 |
|  3 |   ... |        2 | 2017-10-02 03:47:46 |
|  4 |   ... |        2 | 2017-10-02 02:47:46 |
|  5 |   ... |        3 | 2017-10-01 04:47:46 |
+----+-------+----------+---------------------+
```

this is my code so far (which is not working)

```
SELECT COUNT(medias.model_id), medias.date
FROM medias
GROUP BY medias.model_id HAVING COUNT(medias.model_id) > 1
WHERE date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)
```

Comment: Move your group by clause after where clause

Comment: Your query can't be correct because you are showing a date in the results. What date is this supposed to be?

Comment: What about ties? Let's say model IDs 1 to 6 were used ten times and all other IDs less than that. Would you want to show all six most top used models then? Or only five of them? If so, which?

Answer (score 0):

Find the count and select the top one using `LIMIT`.

**Query**

```
select `model_id`, count(*) as `total`
from `medias`
where `date` > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)
group by `model_id`
order by `total` desc limit 1;
```